# getTwitterCount method Failed in karma test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

i am trying to testing a angulaJS 's module using karma.i have updated all the dependies and devdependies necessary to my project but  i have one error"Chrome Social should have a getTwitterCount method Failed"
ReferenceError:expect is not defined
This is my file test Socialspec.js:

```
describe('Social', function(){

  var Social;
  var $http;
  var url = "http://grafikart.fr";

  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('App')
    angular.mock.inject(function(_Social_, $httpBackend){
      Social = _Social_
      $http = $httpBackend
    })
  })

  afterEach(function(){
    $http.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $http.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  })


  it("Should have a getTwitterCount method", function(){
    expect(Social.getTwitterCount).to.be.a('function')
  })

  it("Should call JSONP", function(){
    $http.expectJSONP(Social.twitterAPI + url).respond(false)
    Social.getTwitterCount(url)
    $http.flush()
  })

  it("Should return count", function(){
    count = 0;
    $http.expectJSONP(Social.twitterAPI + url).respond({count: 2})
    Social.getTwitterCount(url).then(function(c){
      count = c
    })
    $http.flush()
    expect(count).to.be.equal(2)
  })


})
```

and this is where i defined my angularjs's module and factory:

```
var app=angular.module("App",[]);
app.factory('Social',function($http,$q){


  return {
     twitterAPI: 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?callback=angular.callbacks._0&url=',
     getTwitterCount: function(url){
       q = $q.defer()
       $http.jsonp(this.twitterAPI + url)
       .then(function(result){
         q.resolve(result.data.count)
       })
       return q.promise
     }
   }

})
```

Can you help me?thank you

Comment: You can no longer get Twitter Counts anymore. Twitter have removed it and are in the process of rolling out a replacement in a few months

Comment: So there is no solutions to this problem?how can i test this part of code?

Comment: ok thank you inkovic